# Test Pydantic settings in FastAPI

Tags: python, testing, fastapi, pydantic

Suppose my `main.py` is like this (this is a simplified example, in my app I use an actual database and I have two different database URIs for development and testing):

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseSettings

app = FastAPI()

class Settings(BaseSettings):
    ENVIRONMENT: str

    class Config:
        env_file = ".env"
        case_sensitive = True

settings = Settings()

databases = {
    "dev": "Development",
    "test": "Testing"
}
database = databases[settings.ENVIRONMENT]

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Environment": database}
```

while the `.env` is

```
ENVIRONMENT=dev
```

Suppose I want to test my code and I want to set `ENVIRONMENT=test` to use a testing database. What should I do? In FastAPI documentation (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/settings/#settings-and-testing) there is a good example but it is about dependencies, so it is a different case as far as I know.

My idea was the following (`test.py`):

```py
import pytest

from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

from main import app

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def test_config(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setenv("ENVIRONMENT", "test")

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def client():
    return TestClient(app)

def test_root(client):
    response = client.get("/")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {"Environment": "Testing"}
```

but it doesn't work.

Furthermore I get this error:

```
ScopeMismatch: You tried to access the 'function' scoped fixture 'monkeypatch' with a 'session' scoped request object, involved factories
test.py:7:  def test_config(monkeypatch)
env\lib\site-packages\_pytest\monkeypatch.py:16:  def monkeypatch()
```

while from `pytest` official documentation it should work (https://docs.pytest.org/en/3.0.1/monkeypatch.html#example-setting-an-environment-variable-for-the-test-session). I have the latest version of `pytest` installed.

I tried to use specific test environment variables because of this: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/settings/#field-value-priority.

To be honest I'm lost, my only real aim is to have a different test configuration (in the same way Flask works: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/tests/#setup-and-fixtures). Am I approaching the problem the wrong way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`PydanticSettings` are mutable, so you can simply override them in your `test.py`:

```
from main import settings

settings.ENVIRONMENT = 'test'
```

Comment: True unless `allow_mutation = False` is passed to the `Config` object of the settings.

Comment: Simple yet effective!

Comment: Should the developer manually revert the setting back to initial value?

Comment: If you use this trick in your tests - no

Comment: Use `monkeypatch.setattr(settings, 'ENVIRONMENT', 'test')`.

Answer (score 3):

Bumping an old thread because I found a solution that was a bit cleaner for my use case. I was having trouble getting test specific dotenv files to load only while tests were running and when I had a local development dotenv in the project dir.

You can do something like the below where `test.enviornment` is a special dotenv file that is NOT an `env_file` path in the settings class Config. Because env vars > dotenv for BaseSettings, this will override any settings from a local .env as long as this is run in conftest.py before your settings class is imported. It also guarantees that your test environment is only active when tests are being run.

```py
#conftest.py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv("tests/fixtures/test.environment", override=True)

from app import settings # singleton instance of BaseSettings class
```

Comment: thx - this really helps and is much cleaner

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way that works for me.  Consider that you have a configuration file named APPNAME.cfg with the following settings:

```
DEV_DSN='DSN=my_dev_dsn; UID=my_dev_user_id; PWD=my_dev_password'
PROD_DSN='DSN=my_prod_dsn; UID=my_prod_user_id; PWD=my_prod_password'
```

Set your environment according to your OS or Docker variable.  For Linux you could enter:

```
export MY_ENVIORONMENT=DEV
```

Now consider the following settings.py:

```
from pydantic import BaseSettings
import os

class Settings(BaseSettings):
    DSN: str

    class Config():
        env_prefix = f"{os.environ['MY_ENVIORONMENT']}_"
        env_file = "APPNAME.cfg"
```

Your app would simply need to do the following:

```
from settings import Settings

s = Settings()
db = pyodbc.connect(s.DSN)
```

Answer (score -2):

It's really tricky to mock environment with pydantic involved.

I only achieved desired behaviour with dependency injection in fastapi and making `get_settings` function, which itself seems to be good practice since even documentation says to do so.

Suppose you have

```py
...

class Settings(BaseSettings):
    ENVIRONMENT: str

    class Config:
        env_file = ".env"
        case_sensitive = True

def get_settings() -> Settings:
    return Settings()

databases = {
    "dev": "Development",
    "test": "Testing"
}
database = databases[get_settings().ENVIRONMENT]

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Environment": database}
```

And in your tests you would write:

```py
import pytest
from main import get_settings

def get_settings_override() -> Settings:
    return Settings(ENVIRONMENT="dev")

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def override_settings() -> None:
    app.dependency_overrides[get_settings] = get_settings_override
```

You can use scope session if you'd like.

This would override your `ENVIRONMENT` variable and wouldn't touch rest of configuration variables.

Comment: Thanks for the input but, alas, it doesn't seem to work anyways.

I did exactly as you told. Maybe for the dependency to work you have to use `Depends`?
Can you by any chance provide a minimal working example of a test for your proposal?

Comment: This is right for certain situations. What the documentation neglects to say is that Depends in FastAPI only works on routes (or dependencies called from routes), not your own methods. More in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68981634/attributeerror-depends-object-has-no-attribute-query-fastapi) and this [issue](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1693#issuecomment-665833384)