# AttributeError: 'Depends' object has no attribute 'query' FastAPI

Tags: dependency-injection, fastapi

So I am trying to write simple function here, but every time I run swagger, I got above mentioned error.

Here's my function:

```
def authenticate_user(username: str, password: str, db: Session = Depends(bd.get_db)):
    user = db.query(bd.User.username).filter(username == username).first()
    if not user:
        return False
    if not verify_password(password, user.password_hash):
        return False
    return user
```

and here's my get_db function it is pretty standard:

```
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

I've noticed that `Depends(bd.get_db)` works perfectly fine within endpoint functions (the ones with `@app.post`/`@app.get` decorators), but somehow doesn't work within plain functions.

Apparently, I don't quite understand the concept of dependency injections, but I can't quite grasp it yet.

Comment: See https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1105

Answer (score 51):

This page helped me a lot, https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1693#issuecomment-665833384

> you can't use Depends in your own functions, it has to be in FastAPI
> functions, mainly routes. You can, however, use Depends in your own
> functions when that function is also a dependency, so could can have a
> chain of functions.
>
> Eg, a route uses Depends to resolve a 'getcurrentuser', which also
> uses Depends to resolve 'getdb', and the whole chain will be resolved.
> But if you then call 'getcurrentuser' without using Depends, it won't
> be able to resolve 'getdb'.
>
> What I do is get the DB session from the route and then pass it down
> through every layer and function. I believe this is also better
> design.

Comment: Thank you. It's pretty annoying that the documentation fails to mention, in which functions the DI can actually be used.

Comment: This makes unit testing functions considerably less convenient

Comment: I am shocked that one of popular python frameworks violates SOLID Dependency Inversion principle

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem trying to run a background task which was also defined as an endpoint. What I did to circumvent the issue was to create a wrapper around it. I'm not sure what scenario are you facing, but I think my example can help.

Here is my code:

**DB Function for dependency injection**

```
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

**Function definition without endpoint decorator**

```
async def function(args, db:Session):
    ... do stuff ...
    ... interact with db ...
    return "success!"
```

**Endpoint function**

```
@app.post("/function_endpoint/")
async def function_endpoint(args, db:Session=Depends(get_db)):
    return await function(args, db)
```

Now, I can call `function` without loosing endpoint functionality and duplicate code

**Complex routine in need of background task**

```
@app.post("/complex_routine/")
async def complex_routine_endpoint(
    args, background_tasks:BackgroundTasks, db:Session=Depends(get_db)
):
    ... do complex stuff ...
    ... call other functions and pass db ...
    background_tasks.add_task(function, args, db)
    return "all good!"
```

Comment: Nice workaround but I would not mix the data manipulation layer(let say repository) with  the top layer(API endpoints) of my application. I would do the old style  surrounding my db manipulation code with try/finally and close the  DB  in the finally in the repo layer

Comment: And an alternative way would be to use pre-built function next(<generator_fun>). for this answer's case, to access db use this ---    db = next(get_db())

Answer (score 1):

The [`fastapi.Depends`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/reference/dependencies/#depends) function is part of the [FastAPI dependency injection](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/) system. Its documented use-case is in a signature of a FastAPI "endpoint" function, i.e. one decorated with `@app.get`, etc. The FastAPI dependency injection doesn't work in functions without that decorator.

However, if you don't need dependency injection but just want to access your database in an arbitrary function, you can just give it a valid database session instance, e.g. one returned by your `get_db` generator:

```
generator = get_db()
session = next(generator)
authenticate_user("bob", "***", session)
```

This way you could even call a legitimate "endpoint" function explicitly:

```
@app.get("/")
async def get_root(session: Session = Depends(get_session)):
    pass

await get_root(next(get_session()))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from fastapi import Depends
from fastapi.params import Depends as DependsType
from sqlmodel import Session


class SessionMixin:
    __session: Session = Depends(get_session)

    @property
    def session(self) -> Session:
        if isinstance(self.__session, DependsType):
            return next(get_session())
        return self.__session
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).