# AttributeError: 'Depends' object has no attribute 'query'

Tags: python, dependency-injection, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm new to this.

Here is my generator function to retrieve database object:

```
def get_db_session():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

Then I have a method to get a user from my database:

```
def get_user_from_db(email: str, db: Session = Depends(get_db_session)):
    user = db.query(User).filter(User.email == email).first()
    return user
```

Then I have my route, where I use dependency:

```
@app.post("/initialize_user")
def initialize_user(email: str, db: Session = Depends(get_db_session)):
    # Check if the user already exists in the database
    existing_user = get_user_from_db(email, db)

    if existing_user:
        # User already exists, return their information
        return {
            "email": existing_user.email,
            "credit_balance": existing_user.credit_balance,
            "subscription_type": existing_user.subscription_type
        }
    else:
        # Initialize a new user with default values
        new_user = User(email=email, credit_balance=20, subscription_type="trial")
        db.add(new_user)
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(new_user)
        return {
            "email": new_user.email,
            "credit_balance": new_user.credit_balance,
            "subscription_type": new_user.subscription_type
        }
```

And I received an error:

```
user = db.query(User).filter(User.email == email).first()
AttributeError: 'Depends' object has no attribute 'query'
```

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68981634/attributeerror-depends-object-has-no-attribute-query-fastapi), I can't use dependencies in my own functions, so I tried to use them in routes, like this:

```
@app.post("/initialize_user")
def initialize_user(email: str, db: Session = Depends(get_db_session)):
            # Check if the user already exists in the database
            existing_user = db.query(User).filter(User.email == email).first()
    ...
    }
```

And I received the same error.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68981634/attributeerror-depends-object-has-no-attribute-query-fastapi

Comment: @aksh02 thank you. I edited my question - tried to use the guide in the post you sent, but received the same result.

Comment: How are you calling `initialize_user` that triggers this error? As long as it's _being called in a web context by FastAPI and not manually by you_, the `Depends` parameter should be automagically resolved for you. However, it seems like you're manually calling `initialize_user` and not making a HTTP POST call to the resource (i.e. you're not giving FastAPI the possibility to resolve the dependencies for you).

Comment: @MatsLindh yes, I try to call the method manually to test how it works. Should I upload it to a server, and try to call the method using postman?

Comment: If you're going to test it locally, use the bundled `TestClient` - this allows you to write tests/code in the same way as you'd call the API yourself: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/testing/ - you can also use postman/insomnia locally, no need to upload it to a server in either case; but `TestClient` is what you'd usually use to write tests or code that calls the server.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thank you very much, it solved the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MatsLindh suggested in his comments to my original post, using TestClient solved my problem.

Here is how for example the test of initializing the user, and getting credit balance:

```
def test_update_and_get_credit_balance():
    # Initialize the user with a certain amount of credits
    response_initialize = client.post("/initialize_user?email=test@example.com")
    assert response_initialize.status_code == 200

    # Call update_credit_balance to deduct one credit
    response_update = client.post("/update_credit_balance?email=test@example.com")
    assert response_update.status_code == 200

    # Call get_credit_balance to retrieve the current balance
    response_get_balance = client.get("/get_credit_balance?email=test@example.com")
    assert response_get_balance.status_code == 200

    # Print the response content
    print("Response Content - test user's credit balance:")
    print(response_get_balance.text)
```

And then in the same script how you can run your tests:

```
# Run the tests
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('I am in main')
    test_initialize_user()
    test_get_credit_balance()
    test_update_and_get_credit_balance()
    test_convert_to_premium()
    test_update_and_get_credit_balance()
```