How to solve this error 'Depends' object has no attribute 'query'
I want to get current user from JWT token generated after user loged in using fastapi with strawberygraphql
These are source codes i tried to check if user is already loged i use strawbery-graphql
import os
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer
from jose import jwt, JWTError
from fastapi import status, HTTPException, Depends
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from Config.database import get_db
from src.Models.app_models import User
from src.Schemas.base_model_schema import TokenData    
load_dotenv()
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="login")


async def get_current_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme), db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    credentials_exception = HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail="Could not validate credentials",
        headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
    )
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, os.getenv("SECRET_KEY"), algorithms=[os.getenv("ALGORITHM")])
        username: str = payload.get("email")
        if username is None:
            raise credentials_exception
        token_data = TokenData(username=username)
    except JWTError:
        raise credentials_exception
    user = db.query(User).filter(User.email == token_data.username).first()
    if user is None:
        raise credentials_exception
    return user

This is Database connection imported as get_db
from databases import Database
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, Session

DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://root:1234@localhost:5432/ranking_db"
database = Database(DATABASE_URL)
engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=False, autoflush=False)


def get_db() -> Session:
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()


Base = declarative_base()

When I hit endpoint i get this error
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "'Depends' object has no attribute 'query'",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "getRoles"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Here is where i use get_current_user
from strawberry.types import Info
import typing
from strawberry.permission import BasePermission

from src.JWT.oauth2 import get_current_user


class IsAuthenticated(BasePermission):
    async def has_permission(self, source: typing.Any, info: Info, **kwargs) -> bool:
        request = info.context['request']
        authentication = request.headers['Authorization']
        if authentication:
            token = authentication.split("Bearer")[-1]
            return await get_current_user(token.strip())
        return False


from strawberry.types import Info
import typing
from strawberry.permission import BasePermission
from src.JWT.oauth2 import get_current_user
class IsAuthenticated(BasePermission):
async def has_permission(self, source: typing.Any, info: Info, **kwargs) -> bool:
request = info.context['request']
authentication = request.headers['Authorization']
if authentication:
token = authentication.split("Bearer")[-1]
return await get_current_user(token.strip())
return False

Can't use Depends on your own functions, only on FastAPI endpoints (using the @app.get/post/... decorators). See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/77667010/2307934
